# How do we call c++ application from web on client side on linux

Tags: html, c++, web

For example, a client has a c++ application, and trying to access web application on the browser. But the web application needs to run this application. I don't understand how we can call that application from web. I tried that solution https://askubuntu.com/questions/330937/is-it-possible-to-open-an-ubuntu-app-from-html . but it did not work. It only opens well-recognized apps. Can we use this technique to open c++ application and give them some argument, like ./abc -a password -b username.

If you find my question confusing, please let me know. I will try to explain more.

Comment: Does this help? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/497146/create-a-custom-url-protocol-handler

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no.

There are workarounds that would include registering link handlers, like the solution you tried, but you can't call a command line program from within a web browser directly (there are a million ways it could be misused).

Comment: then how we can make the c++ application a well-recognized application, so we can call it directly from web. Like we can open Microsoft teams from the web, cant we open a c++ application like that.

Comment: https://emscripten.org/docs/getting_started/Tutorial.html will this be helpful, if we want to run c++ code on the machine, not in an isolated environment.